# Put asynchronously calls to redux store by using redux-saga

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have a list with "providers" which I have to fetch data from asynchronously. I use redux-saga.

Function requestProvider returns promises and fetch data for each provider.

I use "yield all" to run multiple async requests.

Than I need to push the results from each provider to redux store. I try to use "yield all" to register "put"s. But this line is ignored. I am not sure that I do it right.

How to call redux action to send data to the redux store?

```
. . .

// Providers api
const providers = [ '/apiProvider1', '/apiProvider2', '/apiProvider3' ];

// Fetching data from each provider
const providerResults: [] = 
    yield all(providers.map(provider => call(requestProvider, provider)));

// Trying to push the results to redux-stor, but this line is ignored, nothing happened here
yield all ([
    providerResults.map(
        result => put({ type: constants.MAP_PUSH_PROVIDER_RESULTS, providerResults: result }))
])

. . .

export const requestProvider = (provider: Provider, coverageLocation: CoverageLocation): Promise<boolean> => {
// console.log('promise:::', provider);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

providerResults.map returns an array, and then you're wrapping it in an additional array. I think you just need to delete that additional array.

```
yield all ( // <-- removed square bracket on this line
  providerResults.map
    result => put({ type: constants.MAP_PUSH_PROVIDER_RESULTS, providerResults: result }))
) // <-- and on this line
```